# Lists to dataframe python with optional and mandatory information

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have multiple lists in a list which containa information about index:

- LineNumber = mandatory
- ManufacturersProductId = mandatory
- InternationalProductClassCode = optional

```
[['LineNumber', '1'],
 ['ManufacturersProductId', '7000000142'],
 ['LineNumber', '2'],
 ['ManufacturersProductId', '7000000144'],
 ['LineNumber', '3'],
 ['ManufacturersProductId', '7000000145'],
 ['LineNumber', '4'],
 ['ManufacturersProductId', '7000000147'],
 ['LineNumber', '5'],
 ['ManufacturersProductId', '7000000149'],
 ['LineNumber', '6'],
 ['ManufacturersProductId', '7000000151'],
 ['LineNumber', '7'],
 ['ManufacturersProductId', '7000000157'],
 ['InternationalProductClassCode', 'EC012017'],
 ['LineNumber', '8'],
 ['ManufacturersProductId', '7000000158'],
 ['InternationalProductClassCode', 'EC012017'],
 ['LineNumber', '9'],
 ['ManufacturersProductId', '7000000159'],
 ['InternationalProductClassCode', 'EC012017'],
 ['LineNumber', '10'],
 ['ManufacturersProductId', '7000000182'],
 ['InternationalProductClassCode', 'EC011984'],
 ['LineNumber', '11'],
 ['ManufacturersProductId', '7000000208'],
 ['InternationalProductClassCode', 'EC011098'],
 ['LineNumber', '12'],
 ['ManufacturersProductId', '7000000214'],
 ['InternationalProductClassCode', 'EC011098'],
 ['LineNumber', '13'],
 ['ManufacturersProductId', '7000000215'],
 ['InternationalProductClassCode', 'EC011098'],
 ['LineNumber', '14'],
 ['ManufacturersProductId', '7000000216'],
 ['InternationalProductClassCode', 'EC011098']]
```

I need to convert it to a dataframe like this

[image: Desired]

I tried this and then some conversion, adding None columns but nothing worked...

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Any help?
thanks!

Comment: please provide your input list as **text**, not image!

Comment: @HeadOverFeet answered you in two ways.

Answer (score 0):

```
aaa = np.array(aaa)#your array converted to np.array
bbb = ['LineNumber', 'ManufacturersProductId', 'InternationalProductClassCode']
ddd = [aaa[aaa[:, 0] == i, 1] for i in bbb]

ind = max(enumerate(ddd), key=(lambda x: len(x[1])))[0]
df = pd.DataFrame({bbb[ind]: ddd[ind]})

for i in range(0, len(bbb)):
    if bbb[i] != bbb[ind]:
        xxx = len(ddd[i])
        df[bbb[i]] = np.nan
        for x in range(0, xxx):
           df.loc[x, bbb[i]] = ddd[i][x]

print(df)
```

Output

```
   LineNumber ManufacturersProductId InternationalProductClassCode
0           1             7000000142                      EC012017
1           2             7000000144                      EC012017
2           3             7000000145                      EC012017
3           4             7000000147                      EC011984
4           5             7000000149                      EC011098
5           6             7000000151                      EC011098
6           7             7000000157                      EC011098
7           8             7000000158                      EC011098
8           9             7000000159                           NaN
9          10             7000000182                           NaN
10         11             7000000208                           NaN
11         12             7000000214                           NaN
12         13             7000000215                           NaN
13         14             7000000216                           NaN
```

First your array will be converted to an np.array. A list of titles is created bbb. The array is split into arrays ddd by headers. The longest array is found. It creates a dataframe. Since your arrays are not all of the same length, two loops are used to fill element by element. Maybe someone will do without cycles. But, I could not add an array through a slice.

Since you say the InternationalProductClassCode is optional. This can be done more simply, since the remaining arrays are of the same length.

```
aaa = np.array(aaa)#your array converted to np.array
bbb = ['LineNumber', 'ManufacturersProductId']
ddd = [aaa[aaa[:, 0] == i, 1] for i in bbb]
df1 = pd.DataFrame({bbb[0]: ddd[0], bbb[1]: ddd[1]})
print(df1)
```